# Battery backup circuit

Tags: power-supply, mosfet

I want a battery back up for a monitoring system.

> Power supply is 4.8V-6V.
>
> Battery is 4.8V-6.4V (with 100uA leakage it goes 4.8V after one year).

I designed this circuit but on simulation it seems that is not working. What is wrong? [image]

**UPDATE:** It is working on other simulator. You can simulate it [here](http://everycircuit.com/circuit/6448362486497280)

[image]

Comment: What is not working? Please elaborate.

Comment: 6.00V, 6.01pA, 100 Ohm load - something is very wrong with that simulation!

Comment: @winny 0Amp going to load

Comment: It is simulation error, I changed PMOS(SSA24-E3/61T) with another PMOS (BSL207SP) and it is working